# Execute code from servlet and jsp from button?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

I run a website on a java servlet, which load my jsp page and, under this function, I have a condition that verifies if a button in my jsp is clicked (all in the doGet):

```
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(jsp file here);
//...
if (request.getParameter("valeur0") != null){
            //do stuff
}
```

Then, in my jsp file, my html button, when clicked, calls a javascript function like this:

```
    <input type="submit" name="valeur1" value="Bouton 1" id="myBtn1" onclick='startCombine()'/>
```

Where startCombine() is defined by:

```
function startCombine() {
        document.getElementById("myBtn1").disabled = true;
}
```

When I don't call the startCombine() function (so there's no onclick in my button declaration), the stuff in the servlet condition works. However, when I call startCombine() with the onclick in html, even if I click on my button, it never gets into the if...

I tried everything, I can't seem to spot the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the submit button disables itself (by calling the `startCombine` function) before it has a chance to submit the form. And if the form is not submitted... your servlet is not called !

Comment: Wow thanks! I feel like an idiot, I can't believe I haven't seen it before!